# Can anyone explain the Yearling badge

Tags: support

Can anyone please tell me what is [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=2427065) badge?
It says

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

But it is awarded for me 3 times.

Can anyone clarify the description.

How is the 200 reputation calculated?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [List of all badges with full description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/168333).

Comment: @S.L.Barth, is this just a comment or did you raised a flag?

Comment: @SagarV This is just a comment. But, I really think you should spend more time researching, before asking things.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Meta SO have duplicate target (using rogue search engine can help - https://www.bing.com/search?q=stackoverflow+yearling+badge, https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=stackoverflow+yearling+badge)

Answer (score 6):

You've been a member for 3 years and accumulated at least 3 x 200 rep in that time so you get 3 badges, one per year.

If you reach 3 years and have less than 600 rep, you won't get the badge till you cross the rep threshold.

Comment: So the 3 year calculated at once and combined with each 200 rep?

Comment: @SagarV Per year spent on this site you're eligible for a yearling badge **if you have earned the required reputation.** In order for you to have 3 yearling badges you'd have to be registered on this site for 3 years and have earned a total of at least 600 rep.

Answer (score 4):

You earned this all in the same year because you were a member for three years but you just recently got 600 reputation (3 badges and 200 reputation each) to surpass the requirements for all three badges, all in February, so it was awarded three times. The Yearling isn't time sensitive. Once you're here for a year, you qualify to earn the badge at a later date, you just need to get 200 reputation within the time you've been here.